# How to remove ' " ' from a string that is read by Cells.Range.Text from a table?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to go throug Cell by Cell in a table, read the cells text and look for a matching string `"G"`. I use `tables.range.cells.range.text` to read from the table. That's working in principle, but the variable contains at start of the string the charakter `"`, looking like a non-printable charakter that I need to remove.

I tried to use `Replace`, and cutting the string by `Righ`t but nothing helped to remove the `"`.

```
Private Sub Search ()  
Dim i, compR As Integer  
Dim b, c, d As String  
i = 1  
compR = 1  
c = "G"  
Do Until compR = 0  
b = Tables(7).Range.Cells(i).Range.Text
d = Replace(b, Chr(13), "")
i = i + 1
d = Left(d, Len(d) - 1)
compR = StrComp(d, c, vbTextCompare)
MsgBox (d)  
Loop  
End Sub
```

`d` should contain just the text `'G'`, but it has an still the `"` in front of at the start of the string: `"G`. But this is just visible if I do a mouse over at the code over `d`, even after `Replace`.

screenshot of variable b content

[image]

How can I remove the `"`?

screenshot table

[image]

Comment: Have You tried in Replace function instead of Chr(34) just put """" ? (it is 4 times " )

Comment: @Teamothy delivers same result

Comment: OK... Two angles of approach occur to me: 1) If you select the cell content (the G, only) then check what language is applied, what is it? My thought is that could be a "complex script", rather than "plain Latin" and that the `"` is coming from that. 2) Query that character's length and ASCI value: `Debug.Print Len(d),  AscW(d)` it may not be a `Chr(34)`

Comment: Try even to debug.print b or debug.print d, there should be no " in result. Mouse over variable declared 'as String' You will see " at the begining and the end, sometimes it's bugged like that. I'm just saying from my experience, I may be wrong.

Comment: updated my code: it was vice versa.... Not the first " was the isse - at the end it was missing... Thanks to all for your answers - send me on the right track :-)